# Name for algebra which is commutative up a group action

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, graded-rings

I am wondering if there is a name for an algebra which is commutative up to some group action.

To be more concrete, assume $A= \bigoplus A_n$ is a graded algebra, so $A_n \cdot A_m  \subset A_{n+m}$, and each of the pieces $A_n$ comes equipped with an action of the symmetric group $S_n$ such that $$ a \cdot b = \sigma * (b \cdot a) $$
for some $\sigma \in S_n$ (which depends on $a$ and $b$).
The tensor algebra or the exterior algebra of a finite-dimensional vector space are obvious  examples of such things.

Is there a name for such a property?

Comment: But what is $\sigma$ in your formula? How do you decide which element of $S_n$ should act on $b\cdot a$?

Comment: Sorry for the poor phrasing, I forgot to add "for some $\sigma \in S_n$ which depends on $a$ and $b$". The running example is the tensor algebra $T(V)$ of a vector space $V$ with the degree $n$ piece being $V^{\otimes n}$ and $S_n$ acts permuting the factors.